# MySql query with OR parameter

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

```
SELECT task_name,task_id,
       SUBSTR(task_text,1,20) AS task_text,
       task_project_id,task_status
    FROM projectboard_tasks
    WHERE task_status IN  ('0','3')
     AND  task_assigner = 31 OR  task_assigned_to = 31
```

Here in query i return the rows with task status 0 and 3 but due to `OR` the query returns rows which are not matching the `task_status` condition

I get the rows which are not with status 0 or 3 because it match the task_assigner with other rows and shows the result.

Is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply proper parenthesis `( )`. You need to apply parenthesis for the condition `(task_assigner = 31 OR task_assigned_to = 31)`, so the `task_status IN ('0', '3')` and the `task_assigner` both conditions will satisfy.

The working query will be:

```
SELECT task_name, task_id, SUBSTR(task_text, 1, 20) AS task_text,
       task_project_id, task_status
FROM projectboard_tasks
WHERE task_status IN ('0', '3')
    AND (task_assigner = 31 OR task_assigned_to = 31)
```

Comment: @ADP You are welcome. Happy to help.